# How can i join these 2 lists of object where the guid is equal?

Tags: c#, linq

this is the linq query i have

```
var query =
                        from log in newData 
                        join channle in ChannelUid on log.guid equals channle.guid into l
                        from temp in l.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            log.date,
                            log.time,
                            name = (temp == null ? log.guid : temp.name)
                        };
```

and these are the objects of each list

```
class LogRow
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
        public string ip { get; set; }
        public string guid { get; set; }
        public long bytes { get; set; }

        public LogRow(string[] row)
        {
            this.date = row[0];
            this.time = row[1];
            this.ip = row[2];
            this.guid = row[4];
            this.bytes = (long)Convert.ToDouble(row[6]);
        }
    }
    class Channle
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string guid { get; set; }

        public Channle(string []row)
        {
            this.name = row[0];
            this.guid = row[1];
        }
    }
```

i tried many things but nothing changed the fact that it returns the following
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tagcq.png)

Comment: If you add navigation properties to your models then you won't need to use `join` at all, and your queries will be much cleaner and easier to debug. It looks like you're trying to write SQL, instead of using Linq the way it's supposed to be done.

Comment: It seems like your problem is you create a `query` object, but never actually run the query to get results. To do so you need to use something like `ToList()` or `ToArray()` (not recommended) or `Count` or `First`, or use the query in a `foreach`. See Microsoft's explanation [Deferred Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
var query =
    from log in newData 
    join channle in ChannelUid on log.guid equals channle.guid
    select new
    {
        log.date,
        log.time,
        name = (channle == null ? log.guid : channle.name)
    };
```